# Inverse matrix of a special matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, transpose

[image]

$\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ form a matrix $M$. Is there a trick or an easy way to show that $M^T$ is the inverse matrix of $M$?

Comment: **Hint.** It is an orthogonal matrix, right?

Comment: @BernardPan This is not helping me. Your hint is what we are trying to prove.

Comment: What does an orthogonal matrix mean? The columns constitute an orthonormal set. That is, any two of them are orthogonal to each other and each vector has norm 1. This should be straightforward.